# Use lining figures in specific places with `newpxtext`

Tags: oldstylenums, liningnums

I have a LaTeX document set up with `\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext}` in the preamble. There are a few places I want to use lining figures (in text mode). How can I switch to lining figures for a short part of the document?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext}
\begin{document}
Hello, world! These are old-style figures: 123

But I would like these to be lining figures: 123.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands `\textlf` and `\lfstyle` are for you. Unfortunately they are not documented in file newpxdoc.pdf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext}

\begin{document}
Hello, world! These are old-style figures: 123

But I would like these to be lining figures: \textlf{123} {\lfstyle 456}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the `\textlf` macro mentioned anywhere in the `newpx` package documentation? I can't seem to find a reference in the package's user guide. :-(

Comment: No, it is not documented.

Comment: Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Or \liningnums{123} if you are using the `fontspec` package.